# Integral of $\sqrt{(a\cos(x)+ b\sin(x))^2}$ for $\sqrt{a^2+b^2} \leq 1$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

I am currently working to solve the integral

$$\int_0^{2 \pi} dx \sqrt{(a \; \cos(x)+ b \; \sin(x))^2}$$

*WolframAlpha* gave me quite an interesting antideriavtive which is:

$$\frac{(-b \; \cos(x) + a \; \sin(x)) \sqrt{(a \; \cos(x) + b \; \sin(x))^2} }{ a \;  \cos(x) + b \; \sin(x)}$$

If I now were to plug in my interval borders $2 \pi$ and $0$ into the integral, I would most certainly end up getting $0$ as a solution as the antiderivative is periodic with a periodicity of $2 \pi$.

However, if choose e.g. $a=1$, $b=0$ the integral becomes

$$\int_{0}^{2 \pi} dx \sqrt{\cos^2(x)} = \int_0^{2 \pi} |\cos(x)| = 4  $$

Which is certainly not $0$.

Any suggestions to what I am missing would be greatly appreciated.

Cheers!

**Edit**:

**I feel the need to stress this: I am confused about how, what I indicated in the second formula, can be the indefinite integral ,while the definite integral, is 4.**

Comment: What is to be integrated $\sqrt{a\cos x+b\sin x}$ or $\sqrt{(a\cos x+b\sin x)^2}$?

Comment: The integrand is $\sqrt{(a cos(x) + b sin(x))^2}$

Comment: Then, you should fix the title to reflect that.  Your title is $\sqrt{(a\cos x+b\sin x)}$ without the square.

Comment: I think it would be easier to simply write $a\cos x+b\sin x=\sqrt{a^2+b^2}\cos(x+\phi)$ for some fixed $\phi$.  I am not sure why $\sqrt{a^2+b^2}\le 1$ is relevant in this question.

Comment: And then subdivide the integration space in order to avoid the implicit "abs()" function?

Comment: That was my first thought, but then I found out there was a much simpler way, so I edited my comment.  (To others, at first, I suggested the OP to find $x$ such that $a\cos x+b\sin x$ is positive/negative.)

Comment: I stumbled upon this, I believe its called "Harmonic Addition Theorem". I see that it is usefull to solve the integral. The title of the question though betrays the true nature of the question. What I really want to know is how Eq. 2 can be the indefinite integral (check via derivative) and still not result in the correct value for the definite integral.

Comment: Well, the function $\sqrt{(a\cos x+b\sin x)^2}$ equals $|a\cos x+b\sin x|$.  You can check whether wolframalpha gives the correct result when $a\cos x+b\sin x$ is positive/negative directly.

Answer (score 2):

Letting $\phi$ satisfy
$$ \cos\phi=\frac{b}{a^2+b^2},\sin\phi=\frac{a}{a^2+b^2}$$
one has
\begin{eqnarray}
&&\int_0^{2 \pi} \sqrt{(a\cos(x)+ b \sin(x))^2}dx\\
&=&\int_0^{2 \pi} |a\cos(x)+ b \sin(x)|dx\\
&=&\int_0^{2 \pi} \sqrt{a^2+b^2}|\sin(x+\phi)|dx\\
&=&\sqrt{a^2+b^2}\int_0^{2 \pi}|\sin(x)|dx\\
&=&4\sqrt{a^2+b^2}.
\end{eqnarray}

Comment: very nicely done (+1)

Comment: @clathratus, you are great!